# Does there exist topology $T$ on the real numbers such that the class of $T$-$T$-continuous and uniformly continuous functions coincide?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, real-numbers, uniform-continuity

Does there exists a topology $T$ on the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ such that the $T$-$T$-continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ are precisely the uniformly continuous functions? By uniformly continuous, I mean the standard definition of uniformly continuous.

Comment: There is no such thing as $T$-continuous functions.

Comment: @Jakobian why not? If $T$ is the usual Euclidean topology, then the $T$-continuous functions are the usual continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If you want to talk about continuity in terms of topologies then you need to do it similarly how we talk about measurable functions, you say something is $(\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B})$-measurable when $f^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{A}$ for $B\in\mathcal{B}$. Similarly you're ought to say what is the topology both on the domain, AND on the codomain.

Comment: And you seem to be repeatedly asking the same type of question without fixing this.

Comment: @Jakobian I agree with you that the topologies in the domain and codomain are both relevant. But since the OP is considering functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, it's reasonable to assume both are equipped with the same topology $T$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman In example of measure theory, we say a Lebesgue measurable function is a function where domain is equipped with Lebesgue measurable sets, but codomain with Borel measurable sets. So is it really reasonable if there are exceptions like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such topology doesn't exist, this is just a simple modification of answer by RT1 in another post.

Suppose there exists a topology $T$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous in Euclidean metric iff $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is $T$-$T$-continuous.

1. $T$ is $T_1$: See argument in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4567589/476484) by RT1. Let $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$ be distinct, pick non-empty proper open set $B$ (such must exists since $T$ must be non-trivial) and let $A$ be its complement, let $f$ map $A$ to $\{a\}$ and $B$ to $\{b\}$. Then since $f$ is not uniformly continuous, its not $T$-$T$-continuous, so $A$ is not open. There is $U\in T$ with $f^{-1}(U) = A$ and then $U$ is a neighbourhood of $a$ which is not a neighbourhood of $B$.
2. Closed rays are closed with respect to $T$. Let $[a, \infty)$ be an interval and $f$ be defined to be constant $c$ on $[a, \infty)$, and linear and injective on $(-\infty, a]$. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous and $T$ is $T_1$, we have that $f^{-1}(c) = [a, \infty)$ is closed. Similar argument will show that $(-\infty, a]$ is closed.
3. $T$ contains the Euclidean topology. Since open rays are open, all open intervals are open, so all open sets in Euclidean topology are open.

Then its simple, let $f(x) = x^2$, then $f$ restricted to any bounded open interval $(a, b)$ has a uniformly continuous extension (for exaple, extend it to be linear on $(-\infty, a]$ and $[b, \infty)$), so $$f\restriction_{(a, b)}:((a, b), T\restriction_{(a, b)})\to (\mathbb{R}, T)$$ is continuous. From gluing lemma it follows that $f$ is $T$-$T$-continuous, but this is impossible since $x\mapsto x^2$ is not uniformly continuous.

In fact all of the uniformly continuous functions considered above are Lipschitz, so this also proves that there is no such topology for Lipschitz continuous functions.